# IIS 10.0 adding disallowed headers to responses on API calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers, iis-10

I have an IIS 10.0 server, and I'm seeing that some disallowed headers [Pragma, Expires] are still getting added, but they are only being added to API endpoints, not when static content is getting retrieved. These headers are not being set in the code. I've followed the [recommended approach to remove the headers from IIS](http://C:%5CWindows%5CMicrosoft.NET%5CFramework64%5Cv2.0.50727%5CCONFIG%5Cweb.config) (adding the remove element to configuration\system.webServer\httpProtocol\customHeaders), and when debugging, I do not see these headers in the HTTP response before it gets sent back to the caller. I would like to remove these headers from the response, but have no idea how to figure out where they are being set. Any pointers?

Comment: Enable FRT on those requests and see what module inserts the headers to responses, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Does your hosting comes with Plesk or something like that?

Comment: @LexLi Enabling the tracing helped me figure out that it was a third party module that was being used. Thank you for the tip. If you write that comment up as an answer, you'll get the checkmark.

Comment: @bogertron Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the comment above.

The key to troubleshoot such issues is to know the source of such headers, so enabling [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) is the quickest way.

If you find that the headers (such as ASP.NET and so on) are set by IIS default modules, you know that you should refer to IIS documentation to locate the settings and turn them off.

In your case, FRT reveals the headers come from a third party module, so you will need to check what settings the vendor provides in documentation.

Note that even if you cannot find vendor settings to turn them off, you might still be able to remove them in several ways such as removing such headers in URL Rewrite outbound rules.